# GoogleMap With Buttons and TableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uitableview

hi i implement GoogleMap in my app but the problem is that i can't add button to it or anything  below is image what i want to do , behind is the map , the button are highlight with yellow . each button will do something and return a value to this activity , the red color circle is buttomsheet that can be slide to show a couple of option , and the blue circle is button textview whatever but it where the location will be shown and where user can click it to get placepicker by google to select different location  , now how can i achieve these on google map where even one button i couldn't add it and if there is a way using the storyboard then it will be great .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9ruL.png)

this is the google map code

```
override func loadView() {
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    view = mapView

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
  }
```

Comment: Did you add textview i storyboard?

Comment: if you want to make use of **Storyboard** you can do more easily, Like just add your mapView in a containerView and over that container view just create your views as you showed in screenshot, if you want to do this **Programmatically** , add your map View in self.view and add other views after adding mapView

Answer (score 0):

create button outlet and add it to your view.

`@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
self.view.addSubview(button)`